# How hide select dropdown based value from another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why my script doesn't work? I need to hide the sem dropdown when branch dropdown is select ALL. I try script below but it doesn't work.

And this is my script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#branch').change(function () {
                if (this.value != "ALL") {
                    $('#sem').show();
                } else {
                    $('#sem').hide();
                }

            });
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body onload=showCourses(str="ALL")>

<select name="branch" id="branch" onchange="showCourses()">
<option value="ALL" selected='ALL'>ALL</option>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM app GROUP BY app_cn ORDER BY app_cn");
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['app_cn'].'">'.$row['app_cn'].'</option>';
        }?>
</select>
<select name="sem" id="sem" onchange="showCourses()">
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM app GROUP BY app_plan_no ORDER BY app_plan_no");
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['app_plan_no'].'">'.$row['app_plan_no'].'</option>';
        }?>
</select>
```

Comment: What does `showCourses()` do?

Comment: I use that for combobox.

Comment: Don't paste your PHP code for a question tagged `javascript` `jquery`, give us the resulting HTML. Your solution : at least, press F12.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bjf9d/2/

Comment: `this.value` might not work in old browsers. Use `$(this).val()` to get around incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

check for this in if statement:
$('option:selected', this).val()

Comment: Isn't that the same as `$(this).val()`?

Comment: I don't see the difference. The value of a `<select>` is defined to be the value of the selected option.

Comment: Oh, You're right..
Last i get error with this.val(), when i'm try to get back select element value.
So i thinked that was your script fault.
My mistake, sorry for wrong answer.

Comment: I think old versions of IE may not understand `this.value`. jQuery hides this incompatibility with `.val()`.